# Why is RestSharp RestClient ExecuteAsync<FileContentResult> returning *Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.*?

Tags: c#, restsharp, filecontentresult

I'm calling a microservice API using RestSharp with a POST message in a RestClient ExecuteAsync call for testing purposes. The data is coming back null and an error message is being returned as *Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.*

The call works otherwise in the normal course of using the API in our application. The API returns a FileContentResult. I see information in the Content.

```cs
        public static async Task<IRestResponse<FileContentResult>> ExecuteAsyncFileRequests(this RestClient client, IRestRequest request)
        {
            var response = await client.ExecuteAsync<FileContentResult>(request);
            return response;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server probably returns some error as HTML, and deserialization of the response fails for that reason. It's easy to check by calling

```
var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

and inspecting the `response.Content` property.